# Asynchronous functions in Google AppMaker

Tags: asynchronous, google-bigquery, google-app-maker

I have a function `BigQueryGetEmail()` that query requester Manager info from BigQuery. I call the code in order to get the info and pass it to a variable. But the problem is because JS is a single threaded language, so I think that it skips the code where I call the `BigQueryGetEmail()` function before it finish querying the info that I need. The effect is when I assign it to a variable for sure it will return an error because there is no data yet.

I have tried to put the variable assignment inside the callback of the `BigQueryGetEmail()` yet still not have time to capture data. Also tried async function but it doesn't seem like it works on AppMaker. The query function is working as expected when I test it out. It returns the requester Manager's email.

```
//run Query to get Manager email info base on requester email
var email = google.script.run.BigQueryGetEmail(emailRequester);

//assign email value to draft.email;
draft.Email = email;

//create record
createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
```

I expect the query will get the requester Manager's email address first, then pass the value to `draft.Email` first before save the record.

Answer (score 0):

The client-side api **google.script.run** has a failure handler and a success handler. To read more about how it work please refer to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

Basically you need to reorganize your code to look something like this:

```
function successHandler(email){
    //assign email value to draft.email;
    draft.Email = email;

    //create record
    createDatasource.createItem(function(createdRecord) { });
}

function failureHandler(error){
    console.log(error);
}

//run Query to get Manager email info base on requester email
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandler).withFailureHandler(failureHandler).BigQueryGetEmail(emailRequester);
```

Comment: had tried this also but seems that it's not working also .. wonder if the `BigQueryGetEmail` function is wrong instead so I post another question https://stackoverflow.com/q/54192453/9426876