# Querying data from BigQuery and return a single data into Google AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-app-maker

From my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54178050/9426876), I think it is the problem to my server-script function that queries the data from BigQuery. Following are my code to queries HOD email base on requester email address.

```
//To fetch requester's HOD email address
function BigQueryGetEmail(emailRequester){

  // Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
  // Cloud Platform project.
  var projectId = 'xxxxxx-xxx-stg';

  query = '#standardSQL \n SELECT SUPV_EMAIL_A FROM `xxxxx-xxx-stg.xxxxx.vw_HOD_email` WHERE EMP_EMAIL_A = "' + emailRequester + '";';

  var request = {
    query: query,
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
      pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
    });
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  // Append the results.
  var data = new Array(rows.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var cols = rows[i].f;
    data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
    }
  }
  console.log('HOD email: ' + data);
  return data.toString();
}
```

The weird thing is that when I `console.log` data it return the HOD email address. But the function won't return the data result when ever I call the `BigQueryGetEmail` function. Following is the caller function:

```
function getHOD(){
  var ownerEmail = app.pages.Main.descendants.TextBox1.value;
  var HODemailfield = app.pages.Main.descendants.TextBox2.value;

  function successHandler(email){
  //assign email value to widget;
    HODemailfield = email;
  }

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successHandler).BigQueryGetEmail(ownerEmail);  
}
```

The widget `TextBox2` doesn't reflect any data nor error which is I believe it is because of the `BigQueryGetEmail` function doesn't return any data.

Can anyone guide me on the correct way how to return the query result when I call the `BigQueryGetEmail` function? had tried several ways but still stuck.

Comment: Data is array type and you are returning its toString. What happens when you consol data.toString() and not data? What happens if you return data as is and do the toString() on the caller func?

Comment: So this is the caller function

`function getHOD(){
  var ownerEmail = app.pages.Main.descendants.TextBox1.value;
  var HODemailfield = app.pages.Main.descendants.TextBox2.value;
  
  var x = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(HODemailfield = x.toString()).BigQueryGetEmail(ownerEmail);
}`

yet still getting error which is:

`Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
at getHOD (MainPage:6:66)`